# Spring scheduled task is not getting executed on Windows 7

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I've got a strange behavior with scheduled tasks. I've got the following settings

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
      <task:scheduled ref="servicioEjecucionReportes" method="ejecutar" cron="0 0 * * * *" />
      <task:scheduled ref="servicioEjecucionReportes" method="ejecutarReintentos" cron="0 30 * * * *" />
      <task:scheduled ref="servicioEjecucionReportes" method="enviarReporteDiario" cron="0 15 0 * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

And the executor is configured this way:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="asyncExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler" />
<task:executor id="asyncExecutor" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" pool-size="16" />
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="8" />
```

The thing is, we're developing using linux and mac os and the three of the tasks get executed properly, but on the deployment server which is Windows 7 Server, the first two got executed correctly and the third one does not.

I need the third task to execute every day at 00:15.

I've tried changing configurations, but the behavior is always the same, on development and testing environments everything works well, but not on the production environment.

I'm kind of lost on where to look or what is wrong with this.

The bean is declared like this:

```
<bean id="servicioEjecucionReportes" class="com.mycompany.beans.ServicioEjecucionReportesImpl" />
```

And the interface is:

```
public interface ServicioEjecucionReportes {

   public void ejecutar();

   public void ejecutarReintentos();

   public void enviarReporteDiario();
}
```

EDIT: Extra info, on the server logs we dont see even the task trying to run, the spring version is 3.1.0.

Comment: Again this is speculation but can you just try removing rejection policy?? Or change it to "DISCARD_OLDEST" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be problems with scheduled async methods in Windows. This is related on how the JVM creates threads on Windows

Try removing the @Async and check if it works

Comment: Yup, it worked removing the @Async, I really wonder why though.

Answer (score 0):

Speculation: Are any of your tasks *very long running* in the production environment by any chance - `ejecutar` or `ejecutarReintentos`. What I am wondering is may be your asyncExecutor threadpool is exhausted which triggers the Caller_RUNS on your scheduler, and may be there is no more scheduler pool available at all?

Comment: Both of the first tasks lasts say 1 minute tops and finish correctly. And also the first two tasks get executed hourly without problems.

Comment: Okay. What about if you only schedule third task alone - or schedule it to run more frequently, does it run cleanly then or you have the same issue even with this

Comment: I can try to schedule it alone but not change the frecuency since it is a production server, also I'm not able to deploy at any time. I'll try and comment.